# Speed up Active Record group by count query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How can I speed up the following query? I'm look to find record with 6 or less unique values of `fb_id`. The select doesn't seem to be adding much in terms of time but instead it's the `group` and `count`. Is there an alternate way to query? I added an index on `fb_id` and it only sped up the query by 50%

```
FbGroupApplication.group(:fb_id).where.not(
  fb_id: _get_exclude_fb_group_ids
).group(
  "count_fb_id desc"
).count(
  "fb_id"
).select{|k, v| v <= 6 }
```

The query is looking for FbGroupApplications that have 6 or less applications to the same `fb_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a block to the `select` method made Rails trigger the SQL, convert the found rows into ActiveRecord::Base's ruby object (record), and then perform a select on the array based of the block you gave. This whole process is costly (ruby is not good at this).

You can "delegate" the responsibility of comparing the count vs `6` to the database with a `having` clause:

```
FbGroupApplication
  .group(:fb_id)
  .where.not(fb_id: _get_exclude_fb_group_ids)
  .having('count(fb_id) <= 6')
```